# Openvpn doesn't connect after disconnent

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I connect to openvpn with this command

```
openvpn --config ovpn file address
```

when I try it for the first time it's ok and connect correctly but when I disconnect it using ctrl+c it wont connect again and this error will show up although I use correct username and password.

```
SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
```

When I restart my computer I can connect with openvpn perfectly.
how can I connect without restart my computer I think my disconnection way is wrong and it doesn't kill all openvpn process.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed `network-manager-openvpn`, you can connect to a VPN stored in Network Manager by

```
nmcli con up id ConnectionName
```

And disconnect from the VPN by the command

```
nmcli con down id ConnectionName
```

Where ConnectionName is the id of your VPN in network manager.  You can list all the ids by the command

```
nmcli con
```

[Source](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-connectdisconnect-vpn-from-the-command-line.html)

Comment: This says how to connect to a saved VPN. User is using command line just fine to connect. This answer does not solve the problem of auth failure upon attempt to reconnect. Additionally, without installing additional plugins, OpenVPN connections are not saved in network manager.

Comment: This method works for me.

Comment: Then you have installed the `network-manager-openvpn` package. If this user has not installed that, and s/he is connecting (as s/he has stated) through the explicit `openvpn file.conf` method, your stated method will not work to solve the authentication failure. I manage my own OpenVPN server, this is what I do.

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited your additional info into my answer. I also have my own OpenVPN server.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, connecting explicitly through command like that has some issues, specifically with killing the process. In some systems, killing the connection through a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not fully terminate the connection. I always suggest that clients connecting to my OpenVPN server use the system service method.

First, you will want to move your configuration file to the main OpenVPN config directory:

```
sudo mv /path/to/config /etc/openvpn
```

Then, you will need to make sure that OpenVPN is configured to autostart your connection:

```
sudo YOUR_TEXT_EDITOR_HERE /etc/default/openvpn
```

Find the commented line that says:

```
#AUTOSTART="all"
```

Uncomment the line (remove the `#` at the beginning) and replace the word "all" with the name of your `.conf` file **without** the `.conf` extension.

Now, to start and stop the connection:

```
sudo service openvpn start
sudo service openvpn stop
```

Using the system service method will ensure the connections are properly established and terminated each time.